# Why is this MySQL FULLTEXT query returning 0 rows when matching rows are present?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a MySQL 5.5.4 table with >200M rows which has a FULLTEXT index on two columns (Title,Body).

When I do a simple FULLTEXT query in the default NATURAL LANGUAGE mode for some popular results (they'd return 2M+ rows), I'm getting zero rows back:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM itemsearch WHERE MATCH (Title, Body) AGAINST ('fubar');
```

But when I do a FULLTEXT query in BOOLEAN mode, I can see the rows in question do exist (I get 2M+ back, depending):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM itemsearch WHERE MATCH (Title, Body) AGAINST ('+fubar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I have some queries which return ~500K rows which are working fine in either mode, so if it's result size related, it seems to crop up somewhere between 500K and a little north of 2M.

I've tried playing with the various buffer size variables, to no avail.  It's clearly not the 50% threshold, since we're not getting 100M rows back for any result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give your version Don? Trying to duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, should have put that in before.  Edited, but it's 5.5.4.  Haven't tried 5.5 GA yet, but didn't see anything in the notes that suggested it would make a difference.

Comment: Well that took forever to generate that amount of test data. I've definitely duplicated it now. Seems like a bug; doing some digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is by design. When using the natural language query (NLQ) if the total number of documents containing the term is greater than 2 million, then the weight will be 0.

This is done on the following lines of [/storage/myisam/ft_nlq_search.c](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-5.5/view/head:/storage/myisam/ft_nlq_search.c):

```
gweight=word->weight*GWS_IN_USE;
if (gweight < 0 || doc_cnt > 2000000)
  gweight=0;
```

According to revision [1346.322.1](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-5.5/revision/1346.322.1) this was a bugfix to prevent "tree overflow".

It looks like you're going to have to switch to [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or a [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) solution.

Comment: Or switch back to a pre-5.5 revision.  :)  Thanks!!

Comment: @Don: That commit is from 2003; it's present in all 5.x branches.

Answer (score -1):

Its likely that these columns are not being indexed.  The relevant section of the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

> The MATCH() column list must match
>   exactly the column list in some
>   FULLTEXT index definition for the
>   table, unless this MATCH() is IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE. Boolean-mode searches
>   can be done on nonindexed columns,
>   although they are likely to be slow.

This would explain why you're seeing different behavior in Boolean mode.

Comment: If that were the case it would return the error `ERROR 1191 (HY000): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`. Not to mention Don opens with "I have ... a FULLTEXT index on two columns (Title,Body)"

Comment: The documentation doesn't indicate that, unfortunately.  Guess that's a -1 against MySQL's docs as well. :(  Also... wouldn't be the first time a poster has thought they set something but did not.